# cycle between headline levels in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, outline-mode

I find that I would like to expose different levels of detail in my org mode buffers; especially while reviewing possbile next steps across many projects.

`org-shifttab` comes close.  It will cycle from fully folded to expanding all of the headlines.

I would like to add the ability to cycle through the visibility of headlines at level 1, then at 1 and 2, then at 1, 2 and 3... you get the idea.

Comment: Giving a numeric argument to shift-TAB will reveal headings up to the given level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jauncho points out, this is supported directly, as the function help shows:

(org-shifttab &optional ARG)

Global visibility cycling or move to previous table field.
Call ‘org-table-previous-field’ within a table.
When ARG is nil, cycle globally through visibility states.
**When ARG is a numeric prefix, show contents of this level.**

thanks Jauncho!

Comment: Sounds like this answers the question so you could accept it.

Comment: well, I don't think I can accept my own answer @glucas.

Comment: It's fine to accept your own answer. It's not that unusual and preferable to leaving it open indefinitely.  @Juancho, do you want to add your own answer so it can be accepted instead?